# How to get planes names belonging to a Body or Part?

Tags: python, freecad

I am trying to generate a Sketch from a body or a part. If I record a macro of my work, FreeCAD gives me this:

```
### Begin command PartDesign_NewSketch
Gui.getDocument('my_doc_name').ActiveView.setActiveObject('pdbody',App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_part_name'),'my_body_name.')
### End command PartDesign_NewSketch
# Gui.Selection.clearSelection()
# Gui.Selection.addSelection('my_doc_name','my_part_name','my_body_name.Origin008.XZ_Plane008.')
App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_body_name').newObject('Sketcher::SketchObject','Sketch')
App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_sketch_name').Support = (App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('XZ_Plane008'),[''])
App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_sketch_name').MapMode = 'FlatFace'
App.ActiveDocument.recompute()
```

**My goal is to reproduce the following above commands in my Python script**. The issue is that when I created my `Body` or `Part`, I didn't (yet) knew what will be the names of the `Origin`, `Axis` or `Planes`. Here in my example, we can see that it is `Origin008` and one of the plane is `XZ_Plane008`

So my question is, how can I have a `getListOfPlanes` method like, or something like:

```py
for plane in self.freecad_document.getObject(body_name).getListOfPlanes():
  print(plane.name)
```

Output would be like:

```py
XY_Plane008
XZ_Plane008
YZ_Plane008
```

Exactly like:
[image: Tree view in FreeCAD]

Notice that when I generate my 3D structure, I could need either the `XY`, `XZ` or `YZ` plane. This is why I would require the list of planes available and select the best one that fits my needs.

I also try to do some reverse engineering with some `dir` and `__dict__` but I didn't find any attribute value that have a `*008*` name. The wikidoc documentation did not help me either.

Any idea?

Using

- FreeCAD 0.20.2 (2022/12/07)
- Python 3.11.5 (2023/08/24)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer here: https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?p=710380#p710380

In short:

> ```
> for origin_feature in App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_body_or_part_name').Origin.OriginFeatures:
> print("New OriginFeature detected - Name = [{0}] - Label = [{1}]".format(origin_feature.Name, origin_feature.Label))
> ```
>
> Produces the following output:
>
> ```
> New OriginFeature detected - Name = [X_Axis008] - Label = [X_Axis008]
> New OriginFeature detected - Name = [Y_Axis008] - Label = [Y_Axis008]
> New OriginFeature detected - Name = [Z_Axis008] - Label = [Z_Axis008]
> New OriginFeature detected - Name = [XY_Plane008] - Label = [XY_Plane008]
> New OriginFeature detected - Name = [XZ_Plane008] - Label = [XZ_Plane008]
> New OriginFeature detected - Name = [YZ_Plane008] - Label = [YZ_Plane008]
> ```

Be careful:

Using `__dict__` to debug or search for a value does **NOT** work. For instance:

> ```
> App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_body_name').Origin.OriginFeatures[3].__dict__
> App.getDocument('my_doc_name').getObject('my_body_name').Origin.OriginFeatures[3].Label
> ```

Produces the following output:

> ```
> {'ExpressionEngine': '', 'Label': '', 'Label2': '', 'Placement': '', 'Role': '', 'Visibility': ''}
> XY_Plane008
> ```

As you can see, the `__dict__` do NOT print the real value of Label, and `Name` attribute is not even shown. So do not use `__dict__` for debug.